# Regex Alternation returning string

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying desperately to return a text string in addition to captures groups from a regular expression using alternation.  Here's what I have;

```
(?<make>(?:\w*|\w*\s\w*));(?<score1>\d{1,2});(?<score2>\d{1,2});(?<model>\w{1,})(?(model)No|Yes)
```

My Data;

```
Austin;1;2;Taxi
Audi;2;4;Quattro
BMW;4;5;M3
Ferrari;10;10;F40
Fiat;4;2;Panda
```

All the capture groups work perfectly, however when I add the alternation statement `(?(model)No|Yes)` it fails, and nothing is returned.  I'm a bit stuck and have tried rearranging the expression in many ways, the application Expresso says the last part of the statement is a conditional expression with a yes and no clause, "did the capture named [model] match?"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tim answered this particular question, but in general, regex can not be used to create data that is not in the original text.

Comment: Two comments on your regex: The `<make>` group would also match an empty string or a single space - is that what you really want? Better use a `+` instead of the `*`. Also use the `+` instead of `{1,}?` in the `<model>` group, it means the same and is easier to read.

Comment: Maybe you could do a pre-process step where you search-and-replace "model" with "yes" or something like that.

Comment: Tim; Thanks for the reg tips, I agree I wouldn't want to make an empty <make>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternation statement means: If the named group `model` has matched, then try to match `No`, if it hasn't, then try to match `Yes`. Both fail for obvious reasons. What do you intend to do with the alternation?

Comment: Mmmmm, think I got confused because I've been able to return no as an output.  I understand what your saying now, after a think.

What I was trying todo was substitute the make with another, based on whether I found it or not.  Returning a slightly different string, for example Quattro would be returned as A3.

Comment: I see, but as Max S. wrote, that can't be done in a regex, only in your program.